# On an ssh terminal, how can I inject text as though it was a keyboard onto an x-display that I'm not connected to?

Tags: linux, debian, xorg

As root user in debian, is there a way to inject text onto an X DISPLAY that I'm not physically at or that I'm not VNC'd into?  I'd like to be able to do something like the following in a shell:

```
echo hi > SOMETHING DISPLAY=:0
```

And doing so would be similar to typing "hi" on a keyboard connected to X display :0.  The program that is currently focused would receive the keyboard events.

There might be some `/dev/*tty*` that might help me accomplish this, but I'm not sure how this is done.

Comment: Not to X, but to a specific window: `xdotool`.

Comment: That was it and you _can_ do it to whatever is focused on the screen.  Post it as an answer and I'll accept it ( if you care ).    `echo hi | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' | DISPLAY=:0 xargs -I {}  xdotool key  {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xdotool` can do this. As an example: try the following in your terminal:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
xdotool mousemove 100 100
```

and watch the mouse jump.

```
xdotool getactivewindow
```

will get you the ID of the active window.

```
xdottool type "ls
"
```

will make the current active window execute an `ls`.